# PHP 2 query for table

Tags: php, mysql

hi i got 2 table in DB

u_m table:
id
username_u
nome_u
identificaorM

info table:
id
username
nome
sexo
idade
diabetes

i want to use identificarM in the u_m table to search in the info table for:

username= username_u
nome=nome_u

and display on a table

```
    $id_M = @$_SESSION['id_M'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_m WHERE identificadorM= SHA1('$id_M') ");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE username=" . $row2['username_u'] . " and nome=" . $row2['nome_u'] . "";
           }
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
<tr>
<th><font color='white'>Registo</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Nome do Paciente</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Sexo</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Data de Nascimento</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Diabetes</font></th>
</tr>";  
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . ++$i . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='validar2.php?username=$login&nome=" . $row['nome'] . "'><font color='white'>" . $row['nome'] . "</font></a></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['sexo'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['idade'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['diabetes'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

got this Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a4490951/public_html/principalM.php on line 30

in `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {`

Comment: Why not combine both your query

Comment: you're not executing `$query2`, also you're not using single quotes around values, this site is not debugging service

Comment: @Rahul how i combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about any PHP related issue but why don't you combine both your query to a single one like below. Use a `JOIN` on both table `info` and `u_m`.

```
SELECT i.* FROM info i
JOIN u_m u on i.username = u.username_u
AND i.nome = u.nome_u
WHERE u.identificadorM = SHA1('$id_M')
```

Comment: second query have 2 conditions...

Comment: In that case modify the query. Better to use `joins` instead of subquery. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$query2` is an SQL string, and you want to use `$result2 = mysql_query($query2)` to change it into an SQL result.  You also will need to move the logic into the first while loop, so that you are executing `$query2` within the correct scope.

As an aside, I highly recommend that you learn how to use [SQL joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).  I believe you can do this all with a single SQL query, and you really ought to do so for the sake of efficiency.